# Youtube TV Client for the Raspberry Pi

Tags: video, hdmi, streaming-video

[YouTube TV](https://www.youtube.com/tv) is a simplified web version of YouTube optimized for big screens. My goal is to connect the Pi to my TV via HDMI and watch Youtube videos on it on the YouTube TV interface.

Is there a way to use the Pi as a client for YouTube TV? If so, what's the best (easier to build, and / or less resource-intensive) way to achieve this?

If it's compatible with CEC, meaning I can use my TV's remote to navigate the Youtube TV interface, infinitely better!

Comment: you can try gotubecast https://github.com/CBiX/gotubecast
described on this forum: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=159729

Answer (score 2):

I watch youtube on my TV using my TV remote. I have a raspberry pi with RaspBMC installed. There's a youtube add in available from the add in menu. I have a Sony Bravia about 5 years old and the remote worked straight away, athough I had to map a key to the context menu, and the TV needs to be turned on *after* the raspberry pi for the remote to work. I also have a Sony sound system whose volume works from the TV remote.

Comment: Can you show how to activate this YouTube add-in?

Comment: For starters you need a raspberry pi with RaspBMC installed

Comment: ...and? I'm inclined to choose this answer as the best one, but if it includes any kind of guide, *even a single step or screenshot*, it would be nice.

Comment: Sorry it was so long ago I can't remember. I recall that it was in the RaspBMC addon menu. It certainly didn't require any command line work. (Though the context menu key map did). I'm not certain that it would still be supported now.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst there's no CEC, you can browse to the website direct from a web browser in whichever Operating System you're using.

Another thing to add is that if you are using your Pi just as a media player, you can install an Operating System such as RaspBMC or OpenELEC and install the YouTube addon.

Comment: Now there is CEC on raspBMC.