# Youtube TV - HTML 5

Tags: raspbian

I'm looking for a way to view and use youtube.com/tv.

The search is going on for months now and I can't find any options that work. Everything I find is about an add-on for Kodi, but this is not working for me. I did find [Youtube TV Client](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12430/youtube-tv-client) but this does not answer the first question asked.

I am not stupid, and know some stuff already, but also not the most advanced user, so please be gentle...

What are my options? Some browser? Other operating system?

Currently running:

- Pi 2
- Raspbian with Kodi

Comment: Are you having problems opening that site *at all* (including from a GUI browser), or are you having problems opening it inside Kodi?

Comment: I'm having problems opening the website itself. it says "youtube on TV is not supported on this device."

Comment: Comments [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33472/html5-video-options) are fairly illuminating. Sounds like, even if you can persuade it to play *at all*, performance on the Pi 2 is still mince. You may need a bigger Pi or a different approach.

Comment: Yeah, but i refuse to believe the pi is nog powerfull enough.. My tv can do it, why not the pi? Building an app myself is an idea, but i don't know where to start..

Comment: Sometimes your 400 quid telly out-muscles your 30 quid pi. Good luck with it!

Comment: 1400 to 60 but i know what you mean haha

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind to use a dedicated operating system image instead of Raspbian and try to build everything yourself, then WebKitForWayland (WPE) may be what you're looking for. This WebKit port is designed to work fullscreen. It has Media Source Extensions support (required by YouTube TV) and can use the hardware accelerated decoder in the Raspberry using the GStreamer OpenMAX elements (1080p with no lag).

This repository hosts the source code and the instructions to build the sdcard image from on a desktop Linux system:

https://github.com/Metrological/buildroot-wpe

Answer (score 0):

I'm doubting there's an add-on or anything (like a browser) you are looking for built into Kodi itself.

If you are dual-booting with Raspbian and Kodi, just boot into Raspbian and execute this command straight through LXTerminal to get the latest updates and the latest browser for Raspbian.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser
```

This browser loads HTML5 and shouldn't contain any flaws, as the RPI Company actually released this ([RPI Website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/web-browser-released/))

I hope this solves your problem you've been having.

#### Update:

I'm seeing where you are trying to go with this, since Kodi mostly lists items on applications and movie services which I find annoying also. If you can grab a Web Browser Add-on somewhere, that would probably be a lot easier. If you can't find one, this is probably your only option for now.

#### Update 2:

Just checked on my own Raspberry that you ***can*** use Chromium to use [YouTube TV](http://Youtube.com/tv). The only issue I see with Chromium is the lag. I'm using a RPI2 Model B+ and I'm getting about 50% CPU Usage each time I open Chromium. If you still want to install Chromium, execute the following through your command line:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/7916060/+files/chromium-browser_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/7916060/+files/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_45.0.2454.85–0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb chromium-browser_45.0.2454.85–0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
```

Then, go to your File Explorer and run each .deb file with Package Installer. This should install each package for Chromium to your system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm running Kodi inside Raspbian, so that is easy.. i do have the epiphany browser, but youtube says this isn't supported.
Maybe there is a way to let youtube think it is chrome or something? next step would be to implement this inside kodi, but at this point i only want this to work haha

Comment: Check out this discussion that is similar. I may have forgot a step on getting everything in my code, but here's the [link](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/33520/41875). @TheundeVries